# Random variable $f(N_\lambda) $ with same law as Poisson $N_\lambda$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Set $S_n(p) $ random variable which follows the binomial distribution of parameters $n$ and $p$, that is
$$P(S_n(p) =k) =\begin{pmatrix} n\\k\end{pmatrix}p^k(1-p)^k. $$
It is clear that $n-S_n(1-p)$ has the same law as $S_n(p) $.

**I wonder if there is a similar result with Poisson distribution** $N_\lambda$, where
$$P(N_\lambda =k) =e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A random variable with Poisson distribution has no maximal value in its support.

Comment: And that implies there is no such result?

Comment: Sort of. If $n$ is some positive integer then $n-N_{f(\lambda)}$ can always take negative values hence will not be Poisson.